# Creating an object from a range of numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to create an object created from a range of numbers, for example **given the following data**

```
amount: 100
step: 5
```

I would like to create an object range with 20 steps (100 divided by 5), **which would look like this**

```
{
    0: {label: 0},
    5: {label: 5},
    10: {label: 10}
    ...
    100: {label: 100}
}
```

#### I nearly got there using an Array

I found out how to create an array which holds the required objects inside, but it's nested one level deep, and it's not an object.

```
new Array(100/5 + 1)
    .fill()
  .map((val, index) => {
    const key = index * 5
      return {[key]: {label: key}}
  }))
```

The above returns

```
[
    0: {
        0: {label: 0}
    },
    1: {
        5: {label: 5}
    },
    2: {
        10: {label: 10}
    }
]
```

Comment: What's the actual use case here?  Why doesn't a simple `for` loop handle it?

Comment: Well a  for loop could handle it, but it's more clean to use object and array functions, no? I just came up with my own solution, talking about rubber duck development, will add it as an answer

Comment: Frankly, I can't think of much of a worse way to solve this problem than by invoking a function many times with map like this.  Surely it's far more efficient to just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate till 100 and increase step by 5 then use square bracket notion to create object key and value

```js
const obj = {};
const limit = 100;
const step = 5;

for (let i = 0; i <= limit; i = i + step) {
  obj[i] = {
    label: i
  }

};

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.fromEntries` and `Array.from`

```js
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from({ length: 100 / 5 }, (_, i) => [i * 5, { label: i * 5 }])
);

console.log(result);
```